# What do the original frame and frame methods do

Tags: framerjs

Having a hard time understanding this method for making imported layers available on the root:

```
for layerGroupName of PSD
    window[layerGroupName] = PSD[layerGroupName]

for layerGroupName of PSD
    PSD[layerGroupName].originalFrame = window[layerGroupName].frame
```

What do the `original frame` and `frame` methods do, or where are they documented?

Answer (score 1):

this confused me too at first, but I found cues to answer this question in this [article by Cemre Güngör](https://medium.com/framer-js/framer-js-tips-ca55fc7cfc61).

```
for layerGroupName of PSD
    window[layerGroupName] = PSD[layerGroupName]
```

This one copies all the layers from the original object with imported layers to the `window` object. This way all the layers become available using `layerName` instead of `PSD['layerName']`.

```
for layerGroupName of PSD
    PSD[layerGroupName].originalFrame = window[layerGroupName].frame
```

`frame` and `originalFrame` here are actually keys in an object, not methods. These two lines copy the initial frame (including position of the layer etc.) of each layer under the `originalFrame` key, so that when you change the position of layers, you can easily revert them to their original position.